# Writing DBPedia SPARQL results to RDF file in java

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, apache-jena

Hi friends I am a new one on semantic web and have some difficulties.I have queried to DBPedia and gotten property/value pairs for Paris. What I want to do is to write query results to rdf file. Below is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import org.apache.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetRewindable;

public class ParisTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ParameterizedSparqlString qs = new ParameterizedSparqlString(""
                + " SElECT ?property ?value  where {{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Paris>  ?property ?value } UNION "
                + " {?property ?value <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Paris>}}");

        QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", qs.asQuery());

        ResultSetRewindable result = ResultSetFactory.makeRewindable(exec.execSelect());


        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("QueryResults.rdf"))) {

            while (result.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println((result.next().get("property").toString()));
                System.out.println((result.next().get("value").toString()));
                System.out.println(ResultSetFormatter.asText(result));

                bw.write((result.next().get("property").toString()));
                bw.write((result.next().get("value").toString()));

            }
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}
```

It prints results perfectly in console but does not write it to the file. Also is my understanding correct that BufferedWriter & FileWriter will create  .rdf file? If possible, could you help me with this issue, please?

Comment: If you want an RDF file containing just those triples that you found in the query, you can use a **construct** query.  That will produce a **Model**, and then you can simply write the model to disk.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to print the whole result each time in the loop. Even if it wouldn't empty the result after one execution, it's quite obvious that this would be verbose and useless. The correct answer is given below by @Steve McKay

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(ResultSetFormatter.asText(result));` eats up the whole `ResultSet` so your next line throws an exception. The empty catch block swallows the exception so it looks like nothing got written. However, that's not the real problem. You're calling `result.next()` multiple times inside your while loop. Each time you call `next()` it advances to the next result. `"property"` and `"value"` are coming from different results! You need to store the `QuerySolution` returned from `result.next()` in a variable, like this:

```
while (result.hasNext()) {
    QuerySolution qs = result.next();
    System.out.println(qs.get("property").toString());
    System.out.println(qs.get("value").toString());

    bw.write(qs.get("property").toString());
    bw.write(qs.get("value").toString());
}
```

Now you can iterate over the `ResultSet` one-at-a-time and get your values written to a file. And please, please, please do *something* with exceptions, even if it is just `e.printStackTrace()`. Then you'll know if something goes wrong, which it will, even if there's no possible way anything could go wrong, because computers are sneaky like that.

Comment: Thank you very much @Steve McKay. I understood that. One issue with .rdf file. The results are now on the file, however it is not a correct RDF format. Could you show how I can keep the results in RDF/XML file format please?

Comment: The file contains exactly what you're writing into it...look at your code, you simply write some strings to it. And you might know that this can't result in RDF which is also known as a graph resp. set of triples. A SELECT query does not return RDF, for that you'd need a CONSTRUCT query.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to:

1. Change your request into a CONSTRUCT query instead of a SELECT. This will provide you as answer an RDF Graph and not a table.
2. You can then get a Jena Model when calling `exec.execConstruct()`
3. And you can easily write the model is the RDF syntax you like using `model.write(...)`